# Change the class of main tag in home page

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3.4

I am trying to change the class of `main` tag of the home page. I have added `<referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="add-ID" htmlClass="new-class-name"/>` in Magento_Cms/cms_index_index.xml of my theme folder. But it is not changing the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added the layout file in the correct path: app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="add-ID" htmlClass="new-class-name"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

After do the changes, clear the layout cache type to get it done.

Comment: Name is `main.content`. I have verified. I have tried with name `main`, it didn't work.

Comment: It's container name is `main`, you can check that file in https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.4/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml#L16
Please make sure you added the layout file in path: app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Cms/cms_index_index.xml. I've updated my answer to add the content of Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml. Please check and remember clear the cache.

Comment: My question is about <main> tag at line 13. You are mentioning the <div> tag at line 16.

Comment: It worked with `main.content`. I mistakenly placed one more file outside the layout folder and was editing that file.

Comment: Great, glad to hear

Comment: So could you please mark my answer as **accepted**? That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new custom XML layout for the home page.
cms_page_view_selectable_home-new_homenew.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

then go to the admin and select the new layout page layout for the new home page.

[image]